# How to create WebGL 2 renderer in iOS?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl2

I am trying to create a `THREE.WebGLRenderer`, but it seems that on iOS, it will only create a WebGL 1.

Here is my code for creating the renderer and printing the capability:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: false});
console.log("isWebGL2: "+renderer.capabilities.isWebGL2);
```

Is there a way to create WebGL2 renderer on iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers on iOS all use WebKit which does not yet support WebGL 2.

Comment: If we're lucky it will be shipping soon. It's finally available in MacOS Safari Technology Preview and rumors are people have seen it running on iOS. Hopefully they'll ship it.

Comment: That would be awesome!